# shell/awk -- print certain fields of a row if a column exists in another file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a universe file /tmp/universe.txt

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I have another csv file, and I only wants to print a certain fields of a row of this csv file if the first field exists in /tmp/universe.txt

for example for this file

```
aaa,1
ddd,3
ccc,2
```

I want to print

```
aaa,1
ccc,2
```

How do I achieve it? I could write a python/perl  script, but i suspect there are more elegant solution in awk/bash etc.

Comment: What have you attempted so far in order to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be as simple as:

```
grep -f universe.txt file
```

But this solution assumes that you list complete words which can't match partially in `universe.txt`. E.g.: listing `aa` or `1` would also match `aaa,1`.

For complete matches you need:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/.*/^\0,/' universe.txt) file
```

assuming there aren't any special characters in `universe.txt`.

Comment: Thanks Karoly. There are "dots" in my universe.txt, how should I escape them using your sed method?

Comment: For a more generic solution see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Comment: Thanks. grep -f is awesome. more elegant than I imagined.